# Prove that there are infinite $n$ which $2^{n} + 3$ is composite by using Zsigmondy Theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

At first glance, I think this problem be relevant to Zsigmondy Theorem.

By  set  $2^{n} + 3 =k$  and then become  $2^{n} -1^{n}   = k-4$

Which $2^{n} -1^{n}  $  has at least one primitive prime factor except $2^{6} -1^{6}  $

Am I on the right way? , to prove there are infinite $n$ which  $2^{n} +3 $is composite.

Thank you and I appreciate any reply.

Comment: Does the problem asks you to use the ZT, or does it ask you to prove that $2^n+3$ is composite and you believe that ZT helps?

Comment: @N.S. The problem doesn't ask me to use ZT, I believe it relevant to ZT by myself.

Comment: There are infinitely many numbers of this form which are divisible by 5. Also there are infinitely many divisible by 7. Also there are infinitely many divisible by 11. Also there are infinitely many divisible by 19. Also there are infinitely many divisible by 67.

Comment: Maybe ZT could help, but I don't see it... Anyhow, even if ZT would help, that would be a huge overkill.

Answer (score 3):

It's a wierd problem.

My argument would be: if $n$ is of the form $4k + 1$, then $2^n + 3$ is divisible by $5$.

Hence composite for all $k > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
$$2^{3n+2}+3 \equiv 0 \pmod{7} \\
2^{10n+3}+3 \equiv 0 \pmod{11} \\
2^{18n+4}+3 \equiv 0 \pmod{19} \\
2^{66n+6}+3 \equiv 0 \pmod{67} $$

and so on. As longa s you find ONE solution $(a,p)$ such that 
$$2^a+3 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$
for some prime $p$ you get for free that $2^{(p-1)n+a}+3$ is divisible by $p$ and hence composite for all $n$.

You can always find such $(a,p)$ by picking an $a$ at random and picking $p|2^a+3$.

Comment: I'm curious that is it possible to apply  ZT to this problem?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A256396